# Объединения адреса диапазона и вычисляемой формулы в Google Sheets

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Пытаюсь объединить внутри адреса диапазона непосредственно сам адрес + формулу, которая вычисляет одну из его границ - и ничего не выходит. Можно ли обойтись стандартными формулами или придется писать скрипт?
Чтобы было проще понять что я имею в виду приведу пример (ничего общего с реальностью он не имеет, просто интересно можно ли что-то сделать):

Есть формула:

```
=ВПР(A1;$B$2:$B$9;0)
```

Вместо девятки - нужно подставить значение, которое находится формулой, к примеру через ПОИСКПОЗ.
Собрав ссылку на диапазон и формулу получаю следующее:

```
=ВПР(A1;$B$2:$B$&ПОИСКПОЗ(С2;Sheet!B:B;0);0)
```

Spreadsheet выдает ошибку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ДВССЫЛ(INDIRECT)` -формирует ссылку из текста

```
=ВПР(A1;ДВССЫЛ($B$2:$B$&ПОИСКПОЗ(С2;Sheet!$B$1:$B$99;0));0)
=VLOOKUP(A1;INDIRECT("$B$2:$B$"&MATCH(С2;Sheet!$B$1:$B$99;0));0)
```

Comment: К сожалению не работает, синтаксическая ошибка в формуле.

Расшарил таблицу:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lPoZgeEycyKqjRH6ed6pvKgXT_14lNbzLllBgE24rkk/edit?usp=sharing

В ней пример.
Может я что-то не так прописал?

Comment: `С` поменял на `C`

Comment: Формула копировалась из заглавного сообщения. Буква *С* кириллическая.